# Erasing only drawings and not the image templates in my drawing program

Tags: javascript, drawing

my drawing program has a function which you can choose an image and it gets drawn on the canvas and you can draw over it and color it

using the brush or a pencil after choosing an image draws them beneath the image which is how i want it to work

but because i set the canvas after choosing an image to:
`ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";`
each new layer is being drawn under the previous

The goal is to make the eraser erase the brush and pencil drawings but not the image chosen

here's the code:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
const ctx =canvas.getContext("2d");
let selectedImage = null;

let imageElements = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel img");
for (let i = 0; i < imageElements.length; i++) {
  imageElements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    selectedImage = imageElements[i];
    drawSelectedImage();
  });
}

function drawSelectedImage() {
        if (selectedImage) {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          let image = new Image();
          image.onload = function () {
            let x = (canvas.width - image.width) / 2;
            let y = (canvas.height - image.height) / 2;
            ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
          };
          image.src = selectedImage.src;
        }
      }

const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName === "IMG") {
      const img = e.target;
      const imgWidth = img.clientWidth;
      const imgHeight = img.clientHeight;
      const canvasWidth = canvas.width;
      const canvasHeight = canvas.height;
      const x = (canvasWidth - imgWidth) / 4.5; // Calculate the x-coordinate to center the image
      const y = (canvasHeight - imgHeight) / 65; // Calculate the y-coordinate to center the image
      const newImgWidth = imgWidth * 2.8; // Set the new image width to be half of the original size
      const newImgHeight = imgHeight * 2.8; // Set the new image height to be half of the original size
  
      // Get the canvas context
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
    
      // Set globalCompositeOperation to "destination-over" to draw new shapes behind existing shapes
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
      //ctx.drawImage(chosenImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

       
      // Draw the image on the canvas at the center
      //ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, newImgWidth, newImgHeight);



      canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
      canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);





      
            
      let isDrawing = false;
      
      
      function startDrawing(e) {
        isDrawing = true;
        if (selectedTool === "eraser") {
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#123333";
        }

      }
      
      function draw(e) {
        if (!isDrawing) return;
        
        ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        ctx.stroke();
        
        lastX = e.offsetX;
        lastY = e.offsetY;
      }
      
      function stopDrawing() {
        ctx.closePath();
        isDrawing = false;
        if (e.type != "mousedown") {
          paths_array.push(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));
          paths_index += 1;
        }
      }

    }

  };
```

i tried to ctx.globalCompositeOperation for the eraser tool after choosing an image, but either it just erases everything or does something completley different